# Dealing with duplicate values but with some different values

Tags: pandas, duplicates

How do we deal with duplicate values in a dataframe that has some values that are different. For example, in this dataframe below we have similar rows but some values like the Male, female, unknown and total (last 4 columns) are different(these represent the number of owners by gender). Do we sum the rows or take mean/median? Or can we just delete the duplicates?
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9QP8.png)

Comment: hi, it depends, do the rows represent different things or do they need to be corrected in some way?

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment. The last 4 columns in the dataset (Male, female, unknown and total) they need to be combined together. I want to end up with 2 rows in total - hyundai and toyota instead of several rows with different population values. 
I was thinking about merging those rows by adding the population count because I think it would make sense to have that many car owners for hyundai and toyota?

Comment: Hi, is it possible that there is a timestamp you are not showing? The strict monotonous increase looks a lot like cumulative counts over time. If so you shouldn't use grouby but select the timestamp you are interested in. Or if your more interested in adcquisition rates you could compute the deltas.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the columns that you want to consider, instead of using `.drop_duplicates` on the whole dataframe, just use it to select unique rows in that subset of columns:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    "unique_values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "column1": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    "column2": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
})
   unique_values  column1  column2
0              1        1        2
1              2        2        2
2              3        3        2
3              4        1        2
4              5        2        2
```

In this example, we only want to consider the duplicate rows by looking at the "column1" and "column2" columns. We can `.drop_duplicates` on those columns only and then use the result to query our original dataframe:

```py
>>> unique_rows = df[["column1", "column2"]].drop_duplicates()
>>> output_df = df.loc[unique_rows.index]
   unique_values  column1  column2
0              1        1        2
1              2        2        2
2              3        3        2
```